# Filter on subscribe to multiple outputs (push to few arrays)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to organize data that i get from a backend (node_js). Right now i am implementing a simple kanban board and i need data from my array sorted to corresponding arrays (so all elements from array tasks with status "to do" are in array "to_do").

I know that i can do simple filter within pipe and get in subscribe only data that matters for me, but is there any way to get as a result not one but 2 (or more) arrays with data (i can also resolve this problem outside of my subscribe, write a function and filter, but i am curious whether this can be done in a neet way without writing additional functions).

I was trying to do this with a pipe but i simply don't know how. Simple putting few times filter in method will filter array and return nothing (there are no tasks that are done and to do at the same time).

**board-view.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../shared/models/task';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of, pipe } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-board-view',
  templateUrl: './board-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./board-view.component.css']
})
export class BoardViewComponent implements OnInit {

  tasks: Task[];
  token: string = '';

  tracks = ['none', 'to do', 'in progres', 'in review', 'done'];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

    this.http.get<Task[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks',
      { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'x-auth-token': this.token }) })
      .pipe(map(res => res.filter(task => task.status === 'to do')))
        .subscribe
        (data => this.tasks = data);
  }
}
```

**task.ts**

```
export interface Task {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  createDate: string;
  createdBy: { id: string, name: string };
  assignedTo: { id: string, name: string };
  modificationDate: string;
  modifiedBy: { id: string, name: string };
  description: string;
  status: string;
  priority: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you can do this using the `reduce` operator.

Here's a simple demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4fm9s?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

For you specific http call, it could look like this:

```js
 this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks',
        { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'x-auth-token': this.token }) })
        .pipe(
          reduce<any, any>((acc, val) => {
           acc.myResultOne.push(val.id);
           acc.myResultTwo.push(val.name);
           return acc;
          }, { myResultOne: [], myResultTwo: []}
          )
        )
        .subscribe
       (data => console.log('my transormed tasks', data));
```

reduce is a operator which actually lets you manipulate the outcome of an observable. The `acc` (accumulator) is the value which you will get an the end and the `val` is the actual value of your Observable (your tasks)

For more information you can look [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html) or the [official documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-reduce)

Comment: yeah @Lados, this is exactly what i was looking for (i wanted to push conditionally whole elements to another arrays, but this example pointed me in right direction and is the answear to my question). Funny thing i was reading this documentation but sentences like: "reduce applies an accumulator function against an accumulation and each value of the source Observable" are a little too much for a newbie like me :)